# is there a way to set the CLLocationManager constants to miles-based instead of kilometer based?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cllocationmanager

I am trying to find a way to change an iphone app built using CLLocationManager, but its setup for kilometers. Is there a way to change it to miles?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure!  Divide all values by 1.609344.

1 mile = 1.609344 kilometers.